# Is there any way to convert vector<Point2f> to vector<Keypoint>?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I can see that we can convert `Keypoint`s from `Point`s by below method:

```
vector<Point2f> points1; 
KeyPoint::convert(keypoints1, points1);
```

I would be great if anyone can suggest me to convert `vector<Point2f>` to `vector<Keypoint>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24623/how-can-i-convert-vectorpoint2f-to-vectorkeypoint/), just:

> create for each point a new `Keypoint` with size `1`:
>
> ```
> std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints;
> for( size_t i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++ ) {
>    keypoints.push_back(cv::Keypoint(inputs[i], 1.f));
> }
> ```

Comment: Great! i don't know how i missed this link [http://answers.opencv.org/question/24623/how-can-i-convert-vectorpoint2f-to-vectorkeypoint/].